# Is there a built-in jQuery function for encoding a string as HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-encode

Is there a built-in jQuery function for encoding a string as HTML?

I'm trying to take the text a user types into a text box and then put that text into a different area of the page.  My plan was to take the `.val()` from the text box and supply that to the `.html()` of the `<div>` element.  Perhaps there's a good jQuery plugin to help with this (if it's not built-in) or a better way overall to accomplish this goal.

For example, if the user puts `<Victory!>` in the text box, I'd want the other part of the page to actually show the text `<Victory!>` instead of nothing being visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for this.  This will encode the output when putting it in the destination element.  Here's a quick demo showing the differences, try something like `"<script>"`: http://jsfiddle.net/6WG47/

Comment: what kind of DOM element will accept a `.text()` method call? When I try to change `$('#ResultsContainer').html(htmlBody)` to `$('#ResultsContainer').text(htmlBody)` I get an error message that "the object doesn't support this property or method."

Comment: @Ben - What is `#ResultsContainer`? Anything that accepts text inside should accept `.text()`  I added a demo showing both being used from the same input value, see if that helps any at all.

Comment: @Ben - `htmlBody` is a string correct?  If that's the case do you have an page I can access/look at?

Comment: it was my mistake....I had an invalid function call somewhere else.  Your method worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If the .val() contains HTML markup (i.e. **text**), that should automatically render if you pass it directly to .html().  Are you experiencing something otherwise?  Or are you wanting to strip the html encoding?